# How to wait before file stream is done writing before I close it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird, fs

I create a file stream to write a csv file:

```
    var logger = fs.createWriteStream('restaurants.csv', {
      flags: 'w' // 'a' means appending (old data will be preserved)
    });
    logger.write("sep=,\n");
```

When I'm done writing, I close the stream like this:

```
    logger.end();
    logger.close();
```

But when I do that, part of the file is missing at the end. I tried to sleep before closing the stream:

```
    await Promise.delay(2000);
    logger.end();
    logger.close();
```

And suddenly, the file is complete. But timeout is kinda stupid solution. Does filestream emit any event when it's done writing. Basically what I need is:

```
    await logger.doneWriting();
    logger.end();
    logger.close();
```

I can promisify any event of course, but which event it is?

Comment: Did you try `logger.on("end", ...)` , or `logger.on("close", ...)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fs.createWriteStream()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) returns a [WriteStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_writestream) object which is a [WritableStream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable), this means that when you call `.write()` you're calling [writable.write()](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback) which actually takes a callback as a parameter so you can close the stream right after it finishes!

```
var logger = fs.createWriteStream('restaurants.csv', {
  flags: 'w' // 'a' means appending (old data will be preserved)
});
logger.write("sep=,\n", () => {
    // Done writing... do what's needed then close the stream if it isn't used anymore
});
```

Asynchronous JavaScript has practically become a standard nowadays, always be on the lookout for a callback function, it's what allows you to run code after the async block finishes when it finishes.

Comment: Can I write empty string and still get the callback? Because, at the end of code, I am not writing anything (it happens in while loop), but I still need to wait until the writing that happened last is done.

Comment: I can't see why the callback would fail as you would still be technically writing to a file... there just wouldn't be any content. You could always try it and see what happens, I'm curious to know!